# When to return in recusrive tree drawing?

Tags: java, recursion

I have write some code to draw a tree recursively. It is based off the mouse click location.

However instead of them being different sizes based on where I clicked, I want them to be the same size. How would I modify my returns statement in order to acheive this? At the moment they return if any parameter is less than 0.

Im assuming I must store the initial location of the click, and stop after a distance from this? Not sure how to implement it without causing issues though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a `depth` (or `limit`) parameter. Increment (or decrement) this by 1 each recursion step. When it hits a predefined limit, stop recursing.

The bounds check should probably be relaxed so that if it's drawn near and edge of the panel/screan it will draw lines entering into the not-seen area (instead of not drawing the partially-visible lines at all).